# TypeScript Definition (d.ts) for Q "noConflict()"

Tags: javascript, typescript, q, definitelytyped

I'm currently working an a project where I use the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) Library for promises with TypeScript.

The newest Version of Q has the method `Q.noConflict()`.
For the typing I'm using the *.d.ts* File from the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/q) Repository.

The typing does not support `Q.noConflict()`. I tried several hours to rewrite the typing to support this method, but with no success.

I would like to use the code Like this:

```
var myQ = Q.noConflict();
```

Where `myQ` is of Type `Q`. But in the *.d.ts* Q is a module which has Interfaces as well as functions. That means I can't simply add something like this `noConflict(): Q`.

Here is the schema from the definition file (not the whole file but with all relevant parts):

declare function Q(value: T): Q.Promise;

```
declare module Q {
    interface IPromise<T> {
        then<U>(onFulfill?: (value: T) => U | IPromise<U>, onReject?: (error: any) => U | IPromise<U>): IPromise<U>;
   }

    interface Deferred<T> {
        promise: Promise<T>;
    }

    interface Promise<T> {
        get<U>(propertyName: String): Promise<U>;
    }

    export function when(): Promise<void>;

    export function resolve<T>(object: T): Promise<T>;
}

declare module "q" {
    export = Q;
}
```

Of course I don't expect to get the whole code but it would be great the get some hints from people who have already written some .d.ts files.

Comment: If you're using modules, you shouldn't need `noConflict` at all.

Comment: The application I'm writing will be loaded dynamically into pages like e.g. google Maps. That means that I should not override global variables (as Q is one). Therefore I guess I've to use `noConflict`.

Comment: No; that just means you need to wrap in IIFE so that you don't create globals at all.  Module systems (eg, Browserify) will do that automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Lets assume I'm loading my application into an page. On this page there is jQuery v2.x and Q v0.9 present. My code needs jQuery v1.x and Q v1. Then I need to use first noConflict() after loading to free up/set to previous the globals, then pass my versions into my module.

Comment: No.  You should run all of your code through Browserify or similar tools so that you never create any global variables in the first place. (instead of loading scripts directly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `typeof Q` as the return type:

```
declare module Q {
    // ...
    export function noConflict(): typeof Q;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This works for me! Thank you. If I do this, I can now use the following code: 
`export var q = Q.noConflict();
var promises = new Array<Q.IPromise<void>>();
promises.push(method1);
promises.push(method2);
return q.all(promises);`

Because the TypeScript Compiler ignores the type declarations its not an issue to use "Q.x" for types.

Comment: I contributed this to the q.d.ts on the DefinitelyTyped project https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4728#event-341807179.